# Vagrant not listening to my port and using default port

Tags: vagrant

I'm using Vagrant for multiple projects now with a per-project-installation, meaning I have multiple boxes. One for each project (or for production enviroment)

When I want to access my first Vagrantbox I access it via `http://sitea.com:8080`. My second Vagrantbox should listen to `1337` (I tried multiple ports here) but when I call `http://siteb.com:1337` I'm getting an error in all browsers (`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in Chrome).

However, when I'm calling my second site like `http://siteb.com` it works without any problems. It seems that my second Vagrantbox just doesn't listen to the ports and uses the default port. But why is that?

**First box** (Which works with port only)

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box   = "puppetlabs/debian-7.8-64-puppet"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "vagrant_ressources/bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", type: "nfs"
end
```

**Second box** (Which works **without** port only)

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box   = "puppetlabs/debian-7.8-64-puppet"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "vagrant_ressources/bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 1337
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.5"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", type: "nfs"
end
```

Both have the same vhost configuration, and my hosts file looks like this

```
# Vagrant
192.168.50.4    sitea.com
192.168.50.5    siteb.com
```

Comment: You have the very same ip in both Vagrantfiles, but not in the hosts files. Is it a typo?

Comment: Yep, that was the wrong Vagrantfile. It's fixed now! Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

When using port forwarding with `Vagrant` you'll usually access `localhost` since the *forwarded* port is available at your host machine. Like this:

```
http://localhost:8080 -> should deliver the website siteA.com
http://localhost:1337 -> should deliver the website siteB.com
```

If you are able to access `http://siteB[:80]` it means that the DNS entry of siteB points to `192.168.50.5`, which is the private network ip of that box.

Check:

```
getent hosts | grep siteB\.com
```

I bet it will give you `192.168.50.5`.

Comment: Okay, that sounds logical, but why do I need to use the port for site a? If I ommit the port for site a in the domain I'm getting the same error when I'm actually using the port on site b

Comment: For me it looks weird, that you use a private network and port forwarding in the same time. Usually this is not required. Plus you have DNS settings for `siteA.com` and `siteB.com` that point to whatever location. (You missed to tell us that).

Comment: Ah, so I don't even need port forwarding when I'm using a private network?

Comment: @Musterknabe Indeed, you can access the server using it's dedicated IP.